# NSIS Advanced Uninstall Log - Incompatible with NSIS 3.0b4

Tags: windows-7, header, include, installation, nsis

Advanced Uninstall Log http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Advanced_Uninstall_Log_NSIS_Header

The example throws errors when used with NSIS 3.0b1 :

```
!insertmacro: UNINSTALL.LOG_CLOSE_INSTALL
!undef expects 1 parameters, got 2.
Usage: !undef symbol
Error in macro UNINSTALL.LOG_CLOSE_INSTALL on macroline 9
```

Editing 
C:\Users\U0147399\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\NSIS\Include\AdvUninstLog.nsh

And changing :

```
!undef ID ${__LINE__}
```

to

```
!undef ID
```

Allows the example to compile.  However, the uninstaller prompts are all missing text, but the buttons function. Note that this script and example files work properly when using NSIS 2.46, showing the Uninstaller text and boxes properly.

How can I get this working for 3.0 ?

Build environment is win7 64-bit, NSIS is 32-bit.

Comment: !undef is documented to take only one parameter, this smells like a bug in that header you are using...

Comment: It seems weird that this is enforced in 3.0, but not 2.46.  Even after "fixing" the problem to only one !undef.  The strange part is that the header doesn't show the text of the popups ...

Comment: I don't see a problem. There seems to be multiple versions of this header, which version did you download and which example did you build?

Comment: # Advanced Uninstall Log NSIS header
# Version 1.0 2007-01-31
# By Red Wine (http://nsis.sf.net/User:Red_Wine)
# Modified by Tobbe

Comment: Built the example : Uninstall_Log_Modern_UI.nsi    in "C:\Program Files (x86)\NSIS\Examples\Advanced Uninstall Log"

Comment: Linked here : [link](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/mediawiki/images/1/12/Advunlog.zip)

Comment: Are you getting compiler warnings?

Comment: Errors in the macro, no warnings I can see. : `MakeNSIS v3.0b1 - Copyright 1999-2014 Contributors
.
File: "inetc.dll" [compress] 11332/25088 bytes
File: "inetc64.dll" [compress] 12458/27136 bytes
File: Returning to: "C:\Program Files (x86)\NSIS"
!insertmacro: UNINSTALL.LOG_CLOSE_INSTALL
!undef expects 1 parameters, got 2.
Usage: !undef symbol
Error in macro UNINSTALL.LOG_CLOSE_INSTALL on macroline 9
Error in script "C:\Users\U0147399\Documents\work\Uninstall_Log_Modern_UI.nsi" on line 80 -- aborting creation process
`

Comment: I mean after fixing that !undef bug.